# Problem with mixing Javascript the PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to assign values in javascript assigned from PHP and the use document.write() to output them. The problem is when I do this, a complete blank screen shows up but no errors are ever thrown. But if I take the PHP out and put in a value such as 'ABC' it works. And example of my code can be this:

```
var comment_text="<?php echo $value['comment_text'];?>";
var bodyelement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.style.textAlign = 'center';
            newdiv.style.zIndex = 10001;
            newdiv.style.left = (<?php echo $comment_x;?>+getPos('browserwindow',"Left")-23) + 'px';
            newdiv.style.top = (<?php echo $comment_y;?>+getPos('browserwindow',"Top")-90) + 'px';
            newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
newdiv.innerHTML = comment_text;
        bodyelement.appendChild(newdiv);
```

I do have an PHP error log and no errors are beign thrown either. The values are retrieved from the database, the probem comes with outputting them.
********UPDATE********
Ok, I had this problem before.

Basically a newline is created like this:

```
var comment_text="cool Beans
```

";

I have tried to remove the newline with string replace but doesn't seem to work. Why would a new line like this cause this error?

Comment: Did you view the source? Is the PHP outputted correctly?

Comment: Check your Apache logs for errors. If you're getting a blank screen it's possible that PHP errors are showing up in the log.

Comment: what is output -> is it $commnent_x, $comment_y, and $value['comment_text'] show up ?

Comment: +1 for php in html in a string in php to be passed to javascript

Comment: $commnent_x, $comment_y, etc has no affect. Only when I echo $value['comment_text'] does the blank screen occur

Comment: try with  `newdiv.style.left = eval(<?php echo $comment_x;?>getPos('browserwindow','Left')-23) + 'px';`
            `newdiv.style.top = eval(<?php echo $comment_y;?>getPos('browserwindow','Top')-90) + 'px';`

Comment: Do you have any special characters in the data you retrieve, if so try to using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) when inserting data to the DB.I think special characters causing you the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var comment_text=String(<?php echo json_encode($value['comment_text']);?>);
```

instead of

```
var comment_text="<?php echo $value['comment_text'];?>";
```

This will protect you from cross-site-scripting attacks by escaping all special characters like backslashes, quotes or line feeds.

The `String(...)` ensures that `comment_text` has type `String` and is not interpreted as a number (if `$value['comment_text']` is has a number type).

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is cleary in the output from PHP.  If you get a blank page, means you most likely have a PHP issue that is **HALTING** the processing of said page.

As PHP is parsed before anything is sent to the viewer, this will result in a blank / error page.

When you substitute your `$value['comment_text']` for `ABC` you remove the location that causes the error.

I am going to assume that `$value['comment_text']` is either a result of a function, or a Database query, try just outputting the `$value['comment_text']` first, then worry about sticking it in JS (which will work if your PHP code works).

As I don't see any of your PHP code, I cannot help you further.

Comment: The values are retrieved from the database yes. The values are retrieved because I've done a print_r($value) and everything output. So the information is there.

Comment: are your database results in `array()` form or `object`?

Comment: @Devin Dixon, you should escape the quotes in comment_text: `<?php echo addslashes($value['comment_text']); ?>`.

Comment: @Devin Dixon and Czechnology, I would recommend using `json_encode()` rather than `addslashes()`: `var comment_text="<?php echo $value['comment_text'];?>"` should be written as `var comment_text=<?php echo json_encode($value['comment_text']);?>`, which also does the quoting for you and supports special characters etc.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is causing an error (sounds like it is) you can turn on your error reporting to see the issues

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was just using trim.

echo trim($value['comment_text']);

Comment: How is this a solution? What actually broke it? Spaces in your comment? OR your newline method?

Comment: Its a solution that apparentls worked sometimes but not others. json_encode works %100 of the time

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a heredoc for the javascript code with %s in the js. and use sprintf to substitute the variables.